# Inefficient HBase record reader

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I made some profiling for my MR job and found that fetching next records for table scan takes ~30% of time spent in mapper. As far as I understand, scanner fetches N rows from server as configured by `scan.setCaching` and then iterates them locally.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to minimize cache load time? Is this a signal that scan was setup incorrectly? Current setup:

```
scan caching = 100
record size = ~5kb
cf block size = ~130kb, compression=gz
```

I thought of a custom table record reader that performs pre-fetching in background.

Comment: its sounds scan caching = 100 is quite reasonable and pls.  verify your scan... can you paste your scan statement sample and table structure here ? if you have column value filters it will take some time to match the value. if its row based, it will be faster. with same scan caching size I could able to retry around 5mb data per record. I suspect, the way you scan is the culprit.

Comment: Maintain records size * caching = 1MB.   is 5kb  uncompressed size of records ?